# Reducing external magnetic field effects using gyroscope

Tags: accelerometer, gyroscope, kalman-filter, magnetometer, heading

Over the past year I have used many different methods of combining Accelerometers, gryos and Magnetometers to get accurate readings of Head angles.
I have also started looking into using a Kalman filter to further improve these readings.

Yet I am still to find a method of removing external magnetic field influences using the other sensors, for example;

If my heading angle was accurate, and suddenly an external magnetic field approaches, my heading angle will be influenced, but to my gyro and accelerometer I haven’t moved.

Is there any algorithms or calculations anyone can think of to override the magnetometer in a way that can determine whether you have moved or not?
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This question seems to be off-topic. Is there another StachExchange site that suits your needs better? Otherwise, what is your exact programming question?

Comment: Are there any algorithms or calculations i could use to counteract magnetometer readings when accelerometer or gyroscope reading detect no movement? I dont see how it is off-topic?

Comment: Maybe i have it wrong, but if you could re-direct me to a beter site that would be great, i thoght this Stackoverflow was to ask questiosn related to programming and algorithms or electronic questions? Apolagies if i have the wrong idea

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to use the gyro/accelerometer as you mentioned, and combine that with delayed filtering, where you wait for a couple of seconds before providing an estimate of the attitude.

Compute the short term attitude from gyro/accel only (start with any arbitrary heading) using gyro integration with accel measurements, and then compute the short term attitude from the magnetometer/accel only using, say TRIAD. Compute the error between these two quantities and decide on a threshold. If the you exceed the threshold, it means there is a magnetic disturbance, and you can thus stop using it in your attitude solution. If they are within threshold, you can continue using the magnetometer.

If you think of more metrics to decide whether you are in a magnetic disturbance or not (such as the magnetometer norm rising to a ridiculous number), then you can add those metric to an HMM, which will combine these metrics and give you an estimate of whether you are in a disturbance or not.